# Blender UI freezes for a few seconds after changing my custom drop-down

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I've written a script that adds a dropdown to the 3D view sidebar. When I change the value in the dropdown, the Blender UI freezes for a few seconds and I can't click on anything. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a stripped-down version of my script, which just adds a panel containing a dropdown.

```
import bpy

def mk_panel(label, mgrs):
    '''Creates a pane inside a Blender sidebar'''
    class Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
        bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D" #Blender window where the panel will be displayed
        bl_region_type = "UI"
        bl_label = label # Panel label

        def draw(self, context):
            '''
            Draw the panel
            '''

            layout = self.layout
            scene = context.scene

            # Displays dropdown (which we already made elsewhere) in this panel
            for mgr in mgrs:
                layout.prop(scene, mgr["shortname"], text=mgr["label"]) #draw dropdown box on panel

    Panel.__doc__ = "%s selection panel" % label  # Dynamic function documentation
    return Panel

def list_choices(mgr):
    return [("1", "Choice 1", "1")]

def mk_dropdown(mgr):
    '''Creates the dropdown that goes inside our configuration pane'''
    # Use `setattr` because attribute name must match mgr["shortname"], so we
    # need to set the property using that string
    setattr(bpy.types.Scene, mgr["shortname"], bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name = mgr["shortname"],
        description = "Choose a %s" % mgr["label"].lower(),
        items = list_choices(mgr)
    ))

def main():
    slowmgr = dict(
        shortname = "SlowTest",
        label = "Slow Test",
    )

    mk_dropdown(slowmgr)

    # Panels hold dropdowns
    # Make panels and register them so they show up
    panel = mk_panel("Slow panel", [slowmgr])
    bpy.utils.register_class(panel)

# Blender calls this when activating an add-on
def register():
    main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: No slow down for me with sample code.  Interesting way to define a Panel Class.  Have you considered using type ,  MyPanel = type("PanelName", (bpy.types.Panel,), prop_dic)  where you can define props in the propdic eg prop_dic["bl_label"] = "My Panel", prop_dic["poll"] = pollfunc etc

Comment: Hmmm... I see I don't get the slowdown when using the default Blender starter file - only with the specific project my add-on is for. What could Blender be doing with this dropdown that the UI freeze would be affected by (I presume) the amount of data in the project?